# Remove class on dynamically create li item

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I have this function that creates a list of `<li>` items

```
function PrintListItems(nodes) {
  while (resultUl.firstChild) {
    resultUl.removeChild(resultUl.firstChild)
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i]

    var li = resultUl.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
    li.setAttribute('data-id', i)

    for (var key in node) {
      var address = node['address'] + ', ' + node['zipcode'] + ' ' + node['city']

      if (key !== 'zipcode' && key !== 'city') {
        var span = document.createElement('span')

        span.className = key

        if (key === 'phone' || key === 'email' || key === 'web') {
          span.className += ' icon icon-' + key
        }

        span.textContent = (key === 'address') ? address : node[key]

        li.appendChild(span)
      }
    }
    resultListItem.push(li)
  }
  resultElm.addClass('active')
}
```

The `nodes` parameters is JSON that comes from a REST API

I then have this function

```
function ListItemHandler() {
  for (var i = 0; i < resultListItem.length; i++) {
    resultListItem[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      var markerId = this.getAttribute('data-id')
      this.addClass('active')
      googleMaps.selectMarkers(markerId)
    })
  }
}
```

That will mark the `<li>` item with an active class, that works. But I want to remove the "active" class from the other `<li>` items.

I can't do `resultListItem[i].removeClass('active')` inside the click handler - that will give me an undefined error. That I can't removeClass on undefined.

Can I somehow removeClass on "not this" ?

Comment: Can you post a runnable code snippet/fiddle? It would be far easier to debug

Comment: you'll have to loop inside your click handler to remove classes

Comment: This is clear to me, that's why I'm asking this. So you want to remove one class when user select one `<li>` not from that element but from the other elements? am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove class for each li element in your click handler that's different from the one you clicked on. 
Try code below

```
function ListItemHandler () {

  for (var i = 0; i < resultListItem.length; i++) {

    resultListItem[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      for (var j = 0; j < resultListItem.length; j++) {
         resultListItem[j].removeClass('active')
      }
      var markerId = this.getAttribute('data-id')
      this.addClass('active')
      googleMaps.selectMarkers(markerId)

    })

  }    
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. This remove the active class from all <li> items

Comment: Argh! I didn't even see that ! :-D

It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

do this before you add the class to your element

```
let list = document.getElementsByTagName("li").getElementsByClassName("active");
for (let item of list) {
    if (resultListIem.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        item.classList.remove("active")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, you could do `resultListItem.getElementsByClassName("active")` and omit that check in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
resultListItem[i].classList.remove('active')
```